# Conexion FireBird

Tags: c#, firebird

Tengo el siguiente código resumido:

```
using(FbConnection con = new FbConnection(string.Format("DataSource={0}; User id={1}; Password={2}; Database={3}", "localhost", "SYSDBA", "masterkey", "c:/base_datos.FDB"))){
  con.Open();
  con.Close();
}
if (File.Exists("c:/base_datos.FDB")){
    File.Delete("c:/base_datos.FDB");
}
```

El programa conecta bien y hago bien las consultas, pero, ¿por qué no puedo borrar ese archivo de la base de datos?, tira el clásico mensaje de:

> "el proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo 'c:/base_datos.FDB' porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso".

Sé que la conexión está cerrada, porque hasta he utilizado destructores y otras medidas y la instancia con *firebird* sigue abierta. Solamente cuando cierro mi aplicación, que hice en C#, puedo borrar ese archivo de Firebird.

Alguien que me pueda ayudar, uso Firebird-2.5.8.27089_0_Win32, Por favor!!!!

Comment: ¿Has intentado crear una carpeta dentro del C:\ y dentro de dicha carpeta, colocar los archivos .FDB?

Comment: Has intentado cambiar la diagonal a diagonal invertida "c:\base_datos.FDB"??